# Time Delay in javascript in a switch div function

Tags: javascript, html, time, switch-statement, delay

I am relatively new to Javascript. I recently found this [switch div function](http://jsfiddle.net/uXeg2/2/) on hover. I have inserted the code below as well. I am trying to insert a time delay that occurs after the mouse has been removed from the div. So that it doesn't change back to the original text immediately. How would I go about doing this? I think I need to use `setTimeOut()` but I haven't figured a way to implement it successfully.

```js
$('.switch').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.avg_words').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_num').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.avg_num').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_words').show();
});
```

```css
.avg_num {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
<div class="avg_words float_left">
  A+ (hover to see score)  
</div>
<div class="avg_num">
  AVG = 98.35%
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ /* code here */  }, delay);` or... `setTimeout(functionName, delay);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setTimeout to run a function delayed.  Don't forget to store the interval so that you won't get any weird jittering with hovering.

```
var i;
$('.switch').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(i);
        $(this).find('.avg_words').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_num').show();
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(i);
        i = setTimeout(function() {
          $(this).find('.avg_num').hide();
          $(this).find('.avg_words').show();
        }.bind(this), 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In `setTimeout` this is timeout object's this. Thats why it is not working

```
$('.switch').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.avg_words').hide();
        $(this).find('.avg_num').show();
    }, function() {
        var hoverObj = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(hoverObj ).find('.avg_num').hide();
            $(hoverObj ).find('.avg_words').show();
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Good answer, just a note: it's good practice to use `_this` or `self` as the variable name when wanting to save a reference to `this`.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda Thanks for suggestion. I will keep that in mind for the next time :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```
$('.switch').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.avg_words').hide();
    $(this).find('.avg_num').show();
}, function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(_this).find('.avg_num').hide();
        $(_this).find('.avg_words').show();
    }, 1000); //delay in milliseconds, here 1s
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjnpy7ge/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that but for some reason it gets stuck on the `avg_num` and won't return to `avg_words` after 1s.